# Как сделать таблицу на весь tableWidget?

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt

Пишу "Морской бой" и при изменение разрешения экрана игры таблица становиться маленькой, как сделать так что бы таблица автоматически подстраивалась под рамки tableWidget?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, \
QStackedWidget

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
SCREEN_SIZE = [(960, 540), (1280, 720), (1920, 1080)]

class Ui_table_add(object):
def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
    MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
    MainWindow.resize(978, 578)
    self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
    self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
    self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
    self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
    self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
    self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
    self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setPointSize(10)
    font.setItalic(False)
    font.setStrikeOut(False)
    self.pushButton.setFont(font)
    self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
    self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton)
    self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setPointSize(10)
    font.setItalic(False)
    self.pushButton_2.setFont(font)
    self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
    self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton_2)
    self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_2, 0, 1, 1, 1)
    self.boardMap = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setPointSize(10)
    font.setBold(True)
    font.setWeight(75)
    self.boardMap.setFont(font)
    self.boardMap.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAsNeeded)
    self.boardMap.setSizeAdjustPolicy(QtWidgets.QAbstractScrollArea.AdjustIgnored)
    self.boardMap.setObjectName("boardMap")
    self.boardMap.setColumnCount(10)
    self.boardMap.setRowCount(10)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.boardMap.setVerticalHeaderItem(0, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.boardMap.setVerticalHeaderItem(1, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.boardMap.setVerticalHeaderItem(2, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.boardMap.setVerticalHeaderItem(3, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.boardMap.setVerticalHeaderItem(4, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.boardMap.setVerticalHeaderItem(5, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.boardMap.setVerticalHeaderItem(6, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.boardMap.setVerticalHeaderItem(7, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.boardMap.setVerticalHeaderItem(8, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.boardMap.setVerticalHeaderItem(9, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.boardMap.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.boardMap.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.boardMap.setHorizontalHeaderItem(2, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.boardMap.setHorizontalHeaderItem(3, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.boardMap.setHorizontalHeaderItem(4, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.boardMap.setHorizontalHeaderItem(5, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.boardMap.setHorizontalHeaderItem(6, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.boardMap.setHorizontalHeaderItem(7, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.boardMap.setHorizontalHeaderItem(8, item)
    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
    self.boardMap.setHorizontalHeaderItem(9, item)
    self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.boardMap, 0, 0, 1, 1)
    MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
    self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
    self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 978, 21))
    self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
    MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)

    self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
    QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
    _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
    MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
    self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "1 разришение 960 на 540"))
    self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "2 разришение 1280 на 720"))
    item = self.boardMap.verticalHeaderItem(0)
    item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "1"))
    item = self.boardMap.verticalHeaderItem(1)
    item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "2"))
    item = self.boardMap.verticalHeaderItem(2)
    item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "3"))
    item = self.boardMap.verticalHeaderItem(3)
    item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "4"))
    item = self.boardMap.verticalHeaderItem(4)
    item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "5"))
    item = self.boardMap.verticalHeaderItem(5)
    item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "6"))
    item = self.boardMap.verticalHeaderItem(6)
    item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "7"))
    item = self.boardMap.verticalHeaderItem(7)
    item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "8"))
    item = self.boardMap.verticalHeaderItem(8)
    item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "9"))
    item = self.boardMap.verticalHeaderItem(9)
    item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "10"))
    item = self.boardMap.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
    item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "A"))
    item = self.boardMap.horizontalHeaderItem(1)
    item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "B"))
    item = self.boardMap.horizontalHeaderItem(2)
    item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "C"))
    item = self.boardMap.horizontalHeaderItem(3)
    item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "D"))
    item = self.boardMap.horizontalHeaderItem(4)
    item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "E"))
    item = self.boardMap.horizontalHeaderItem(5)
    item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "F"))
    item = self.boardMap.horizontalHeaderItem(6)
    item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "G"))
    item = self.boardMap.horizontalHeaderItem(7)
    item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "H"))
    item = self.boardMap.horizontalHeaderItem(8)
    item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "I"))
    item = self.boardMap.horizontalHeaderItem(9)
    item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "J"))




class Start(QMainWindow, Ui_table_add):              
def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super(Start, self).__init__(parent)
    self.setupUi(self)

    self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.screen_resolution)
    self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.screen_resolution1)

def screen_resolution(self):        
    windows.resize(*SCREEN_SIZE[0])    
def screen_resolution1(self):        
    windows.resize(*SCREEN_SIZE[1])    







 


if __name__ == '__main__': 
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
startmenu_window = Start()
windows = QStackedWidget()
windows.addWidget(startmenu_window)  
windows.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Comment: @S.Nick я сделал пример года, если вы мне поможете, буду очень благодарен

Comment: проверьте еще раз ответ @AlexanderChernin, если что-то не так, покажите изображение с желаемым результатом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо задать режим изменения ширины/высоты столбца/строки в равноразмерный (QHeaderView.Stretch)

```py
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

...

tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode( QHeaderView.Stretch)

tableWidget.verticalHeader().setSectionResizeMode( QHeaderView.Stretch)
```

Comment: выдает ошибку "NameError: name 'QHeaderView' is not defined" с чем это может быть связано?

Comment: @rangihrad  `QtWidgets.QHeaderView.Stretch`

Comment: @S.Nick спасибо